# jpa save() fails without any error message

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, save

When I tried to use the save() method of jpa to save the entity today, I found that the save was not successful, and there was no error message

```
@Override
//@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Object> createAdminUser(CreateUpdateAdminUserDto createUpdateAdminUserDto) {

    AdminUser adminUser = createAdminUserMapper.toEntity(createUpdateAdminUserDto);

    System.out.println("-----");
    System.out.println(adminUser);
    adminUserRepository.save(adminUser);

    return ResponseResult.ok(HttpBody.build(MessageCode.SUCCESS, new HashMap<>()));
}
```

This is the result of the console output

[image]

I have used debug to see the breakpoints, but the release of springboot ended when the save() was executed, and the return line was not executed. It was normal for me to use jpa save() before. I would like to ask if there is any way to solve it or let it go Error messages can be generated, thanks

Comment: Could you enable debug output for JPA ? Also try hitting the same query with values you are passing and see if your database engine is throwing some exception which JPA is ignoring or not showing

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to Autowire your repository using @Autowired annotation. Like this

```
@Override
//@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Object> createAdminUser(CreateUpdateAdminUserDto createUpdateAdminUserDto) {

    @Autowired
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    AdminUser adminUser = createAdminUserMapper.toEntity(createUpdateAdminUserDto);

    System.out.println("-----");
    System.out.println(adminUser);
    adminUserRepository.save(adminUser);

    return ResponseResult.ok(HttpBody.build(MessageCode.SUCCESS, new HashMap<>()));
}
```

Comment: change the naming convention of the packages and classes as yours

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give more detail about your code. For example how you wrote repository class, service class or the shape of AdminUser entity for exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies, I found the problem. I have two entities, one is AdminUser and the other is AdminUserRole, because the way to establish this entity is db first, so his fk will be displayed in the form of collection **set**
This kind of DB first allows me to add the desired information to two tables at a time as long as I go to setAdminUserRole(xxx) when adding an adminUser
But when I add attributes and corresponding field names (blue frame) to AdminUserRole, the data cannot be added. I would like to ask why this is the case. I am not very familiar with the underlying operation of the ORM framework, thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: you don't need to add params in blue for admin user role. the fk's added by JPA are already referring to same column based on the relation you defined in your table constraints.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).